# How did Hanuman manage to survive after he got cursed?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman

Hanuman once got cursed that he would not remember his powers until someone reminded him of his powers. But the effect of that curse ended when Lord Jambavanth reminded Hanuman of his power before he jumped over the sea to reach Lanka of Ravana.

But when Hanuman was cursed, he was still a kid and at that time he had a lot of enemies like Vaali and Ravan. How did he survive or protect himself from them?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  When did Vali or Ravana try to harm Hanuman as a kid?

Comment: My question is what happen after Hanuman get cursed, means I know the story upto that moment after that when Rama meet Hanuman during searching of seetha but between that gap what happened in Hanuman's life I don't know. That's what am asking

Comment: If possible please share the source of you had

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan This question is the product of ongoing TV serial on Sony Sankat Mochan Mahabali Hanuman... In that serial Hanuman is child and he is just cursed... Upto now they had shown Hanuman had fought with Ravana and Vali more than 20 times.... hehe... So, this question rised.....

Comment: Yup, ur right. Because of lack of source I watching that serial. Please suggest any source so that I can get to know better about Hanuman's life history, am curious to know..

Comment: @Tezz I think they are distorting the facts and using their own stories for this serial. I watched few  scenes but found irrelevant to Ramayana's version and stopped it. What do you think?

Comment: @The Destroyer you are absolutely right... this serial has crossed the limits of putting non sense things... they show Hanuman being Chandrasekhara, Hanuman carrying Ganga to Sumeru, Hanuman drawing back universe from Kalachakra, Hanuman just about to kill Ravana in child, Hanuman rearranging motion of planets by catching them... and etc . etc... they cross the height of extending serial... I don't know from where they get such ideas... I just watch episodes for fun.....

Comment: @The Destroyer Am just curious to know about Hanuman's life story and I searched online for it but I didn't get any proper source, so I thought it as true story of Lord Hanuman, if u have any

Comment: @Tejaraja Kumara K H I think biography of Hanuman isn't avaliable in detail in our scriptures... You can read Kishkindha Kanda, Sundar Kanda and Uttar Kanda of Valmiki Ramayana to know more.... you can read Kiskindha kanda and other Kandas here... http://www.valmikiramayan.net/kishkindha_kanda_contents.html

Comment: @Tezz So you have any docs and files regarding that

Comment: @TejarajaKumaraKH If you want genuine stories of Hanuman, read [Valmiki Ramayana](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/). There are some minor stories about Hanuman in many Puranas. I think there are many folktales about Hanuman and we can't really trust them. Just know them if your are interested but give preference to Valmiki Ramayana and Puranas.

Comment: @Tezz Exactly. Too much of Artistic licence.

Comment: @Tejaraja Here is the story of Hanumans birth.. http://www.valmikiramayan.net/kishkindha/sarga66/kishkindha_66_frame.htm

Comment: @TejarajaKumaraKH See questions and answers under Hanuman in this site, you get some idea about him. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=hanuman

Comment: excellent advice from @TheDestroyer and Tezz for getting started on Hanuman life. Let me add one more to it: Reading and trying to understand [Hanuman Chalisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanuman_Chalisa#Text)

Comment: @Tezz You pointed out right about the distorted sense of the director and the writes of the tv serial. This is why i didn't see this serial much. THey should have at least researched before putting wrong facts which cause misinterpretation as is the case with this question.